# Add class to wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, post

I would add class to the first four posts.
To print like this on html:

```
 <post id="post-1"  class="classes first">
 <post id="post-2" class="classes second">
 <post id="post-3" class="classes third">
 <post id="post-4" class="classes fourth">
```

My Loop:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=15'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it that way:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=15'); ?>
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post<?php echo $count; ?>">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

In css, use div.post1, div.post2, div.post3 and div.post4

Comment: i use ur first code, but i use post<?php echo $count;?> without space.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [post_class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) filter, if you are using the post_class function

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'add_class_to_first_four' );

function add_class_to_first_four( $classes ) {

    global $wp_query;

    $cur = $wp_query->current_post;

    if ( 0 == $cur ) $classes[] = 'first';

    if ( 1 == $cur ) $classes[] = 'second';

    if ( 2 == $cur ) $classes[] = 'third';

    if ( 3 == $cur ) $classes[] = 'fourth';

    return $classes;
}
```